# Thermodynamics of expanding nitrogen bubble as it rises in water

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

## Problem

An air bubble is released from a nitrogen tank 20 meters under water. The bubble has a radius of 1 mm. What will be the radius of the bubble when it reaches the surface?

## My Questions

- Is it reasonable to assume the process is adiabatic and use the formula $p_iV_i^{\gamma}=p_fV_f^{\gamma}$ for an ideal gas? Note, *p* is pressure, *V* is volume and $\gamma$ is a constant.
- Generally, when can one assume a process is adiabatic when facing a problem such as this?

Comment: I would say it's a good assumption. I know when looking at convection currents, the critical requirement for convection is usually formulated by assuming a rising hot pocket of gas expands adiabatically. If adiabatic expansion is reasonable for convection currents, it should be even more reasonable for a buoyancy situation like this. In my experience, heat transfer by conduction is so slow that you almost always approximate gas expansion as adiabatic.

Comment: If not, a reasonable assumption would be that the bubble stays the temperature of the surrounding water. But if this is a homework problem, you might expect it to say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're right, 'adiabatic' is a one possible assumption for this kind of problem. The other is 'isothermal'.  Which one is valid depends on the particulars of the problem (particularly bubble size). Some cases will be in between and neither will work very well.

First, let's get an estimate of how long this takes.  To get that we should find the speed at which the bubble moves where drag force ($F_D$) and buoyancy ($F_g$) are equal and opposite.

$$ F_d - F_g = 1/2 \rho_{w} A C_d v^2 - \rho_{w} g V = 0 $$

using the density of water, cross-sectional area of the bubble, drag coefficient (~1), velocity, gravitational acceleration and the volume of the bubble.  For this I get that v is about .16 m/s.  So it takes about 120 seconds for the bubble to reach the top. (N.B. this drag estimate is pretty crude and I've ignored the expansion of the bubble but this is all just to get a sense of things).

Then we want to take a look at how quickly heat conduction takes place within the bubble itself (i'm assuming that the density of the water is so high that it remains at constant temperature).  For heat conduction, you can estimate the characteristic time of the problem (meaning how long it takes to stabilize after a change) from the length scale of the problem (radius of the bubble in this case) and the thermal diffusivity ($\alpha$) of the material (~ $2.2 \cdot 10^{-5} m^2/s$ for nitrogen).

$$ t_c = \frac{r^2}{\alpha} $$

I get 0.045 seconds for this.

So, it looks like conduction is the gas is pretty fast on this scale, while the rising of the bubble. So I'd say that you can assume that the bubble remains at the temperature of the water.

This wouldn't be the case for a 20 mm bubble. That would take something more like 30 seconds to reach the top but would have a characteristic time of 18 seconds. that would get pretty gnarly to deal with.

You'd get some thin adiabatic with a bubble 100 mm in diameter.  12 s to rise 455 s characteristic time.

Comment: Good answer. Would you say the isothermal assumption in my case is a stronger one then?

Comment: yeah, that seems to be physically right.  The bubble won't expand too much for that pressure difference, so the "small bubble" approximation should hold throughout.